# Add new column headers without overwrite the original one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The original csv with its original column headers (0~15):
[image]

now I want to add a new column header with number (1~16) on top of original header:
[image]

I use:

```
df.columns =range(1, len(df.columns)+1)
```

but it turns out that it overwrites the original headers:
[image]

Is there way to add a new column headers but still keeping the original one?

Answer (score 0):

In pandas.read_csv(), set header=None.  This will convert the old column names into the first row of data. Then you can name your columns as you did before.

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv', header= None)
df.columns = range(1,len(df.columns)+1)

#
   1  2  3  4  5
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  a  b  c  d  e
2  W  S  D  E  R
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of tuples by joining df columns and required columns,

```
[(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in list(zip(df.columns, np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)))]
```

You get,

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Use `MultiIndex.from_tuples` to create multi-index columns,

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in list(zip(np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1), df.columns))])
```